# Is it possible to overlay status bar over activity, but not navigation bar

Tags: android, overlay, fullscreen, statusbar, navigationbar

I have activity where I overlay Android status bar over a picture near the top of the screen.
I achieve that by inheriting activity style from `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar` and then doing this in `onCreate()`:

```
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
                                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

That achieves transparent status bar at the top, which is fine.

The problem is, this also makes Android navigation bar at the bottom transparent and overlaid over controls near the bottom of the activity, which is not what I want. I want navigation bar to be opaque, and take up its vertical space without going over my controls, as in common activities that don't spill over status bar.

Is it possible to control transparency and overlap of the navigation bar *separately* from the status bar without any kind of artificial margin or padding ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your intention is to get a transparent status bar without touching the navigation bar as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Personally I also tried to use the parameter `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` without achieving the desired result. The problem was that I get the status bar and navigation bar at the same time being "covered" by the graphics as buttons. A temporary solution was to detect the navigation bar and programmatically add padding to the graphics. This is partially useless, as many android users use the `adb shell overscan` command to hide the navigation bar. The main problem with this command is that it effectively hides the navigation bar but deceives the system as the boolean that represents whether the bar is present or not is not changed. This API was completely removed in Android 11.

The desired effect can be achieved by playing with **styles.**
Add these attributes to your activity style:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

You will get a style like this:

```
<style name="ExampleThemeStackOverFlow" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccentX</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar" tools:targetApi="27">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this doesn't do anything at all, with or without FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS